# Cakephp save array data in MySql Database using loop with create

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am facing strange problem first time. I am trying to insert simple records in database with Custom Auto Increment Values e.g 00001, 00002, 00003. but unable to get Incremented value. Each record get updated with same max number.

**Controller Code**

```
public function dobulk() {
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
        $data = array();
        $this->Tmp->create();
        $data['Tmp']['invoice_no'] = $this->Tmp->get_no();
        $data['Tmp']['invoice_date'] = '2013-12-11';
        $this->Tmp->save($data);
    }
   }
```

**Model Code**

```
public function get_no() {
    $strSql = "SELECT
                LPAD(IFNULL(RIGHT(MAX(invoice_no),5),0) + 1,5,'0') AS max_id
        FROM tmps
        ;";

    $result = $this->query($strSql);
    $invoice_no = $result[0][0]['max_id'];
    return $invoice_no;
}
```

**Database Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `tmps` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `invoice_no` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like this should be tagged as MySQL instead of CakePHP.  You'll likely get more help that way, since it's a MySQL question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running into the model cache.

From here: [Bakery article on caching](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dennis.hennen/2009/09/15/convenient-enable-and-disable-of-model-cachequeries)

> If Model->cacheQueries == true, Cake will store the result of queries in memory. If it later sees an identical query, the result will be pulled from memory instead of hitting the database. This is only cached for the duration of a single page request. However, if a record is updated, the cache is not cleared. This is what gets most people unfamiliar with the cache.

So to make your code work, add this line to the top of the dobulk() function:

```
$this->Tmp->cacheQueries = false;
```

As you're running raw SQL inside your model, you might also have to change the query request inside get_no() to:

```
$result = $this->query($strSql, false);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. Its really worked. I don't know how I missed Cache thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below solution will help you!

```
   public function get_no() {
        $strSql = "SELECT MAX(invoice_no) AS max_id FROM tmps;";
        $result = $this->query($strSql);
        $invoice_no = $result['Tmp']['max_id'];
        return $invoice_no;
    }


    public function dobulk(){
      $data = array();
      $tempInvoiceNumber = $this->Tmp->get_no();
      for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
        $data[$i]['Tmp']['invoice_no'] = tempInvoiceNumber+$i;
        $data[$i]['Tmp']['invoice_date'] = '2013-12-11';
       }
      $this->Tmp->saveAll($data);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhav,

I will implement your solution, still I wonder what is root cause of this problem.